# Preventing RStudio from messing with utils::browseURL

Tags: html, r, rstudio

In my [summarytools](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools) package, users have the option to view html results in Rstudio's Viewer pane, or rather in their default browser. Here's the relevant chunk of code:

```
utils::browseURL(paste0("file://",htmlfile))
```

where the path to `htmlfile` is defined using `tempfile()`.

This works fine in the default R interface, but in RStudio, the path transferred to the default browser (Chrome in my case) is, for a reason unknown to me, transformed such that for instance:

```
file://C:/Users/Dominic/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6neOOm/file2c3032b032f3.html
```

becomes, in the browser's address bar:

```
http://localhost:12245/session/file2c307cb3e22.html
```

... causing the browser to display a "This site can’t be reached" error page.

One solution, on Windows, is to use `shell.exec(htmlfile)`, but this would not work on Linux unless I'm mistaken.

Any ideas as how to prevent RStudio from doing this, or on an alternative solution other than `shell.exec()`?